# JOOQ 3.17.1 appears to be generating source that won't work with Java 11

Tags: java-11, jooq

After upgrading to jooq 3.17.1 I get the following error:

> Error:
> /home/runner/work/waste-coordinator/waste-coordinator/webapp/target/generated-sources/jooq/com/myapp/portal/backend/jooq/tables/LoadView.java:[521,84]
> text blocks are not supported in -source 11 Error:    (use -source 15
> or higher to enable text blocks)

It appears to me that it is generating source that is not compatible with JDK11.  Is there a flag in the generator somewhere that can make it generate JDK 11 compatible code?

Edit: now I am getting the following compile error

> [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :  [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------- [ERROR] /usr/local/code/sferion/WasteCoordinator/data/src/main/java/com/wastecoordinator/data/JOOQGenerator.java:[4,24]
> cannot access org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool   bad class file:
> /Users/benstpierre/.m2/repository/org/jooq/jooq-codegen/3.17.1/jooq-codegen-3.17.1.jar(/org/jooq/codegen/GenerationTool.class)
> class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 55.0
> Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

Is jooq 3.17 not compatible with JDK 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the right distribution to work with JDK 11 from here if you're licensed:
https://www.jooq.org/download/versions

Note that starting from jOOQ 3.17, the jOOQ Open Source Edition increased the baseline JDK version to Java 17, see:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12430
- https://blog.jooq.org/3-17-0-release-with-computed-columns-audit-columns-pattern-matching-reactive-transactions-and-kotlin-coroutine-support/

jOOQ is a bit early here, given that Spring will increase their own baseline only later in 2022:

- https://spring.io/blog/2021/09/02/a-java-17-and-jakarta-ee-9-baseline-for-spring-framework-6

But jOOQ will continue to provide paid support for older JDKs for quite a while, still. At the same time, jOOQ 3.14 - 3.16 will receive patches for another while, too.

Comment: Lukas you might want to update https://www.jooq.org/download/ it says the open source version supports "Language support
Java 11 and newer
Scala 2.13 and newer"